# user does not have permission to access gs:// xxx.appspot.com

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-storage

In this application I created authencation, database with firebase. but in my post, which consists of title, content, and image, I only see my default image. I'm having a bit of a problem with storage in the database, first uploading the image to firebase storage and then taking its url.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage

class StorageStore: ObservableObject {
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()

    func uploadImage(_ image: UIImage, completion: @escaping (URL?) -> Void) {
        let imageRef = storageRef.child("images/"+timeString()+".jpg")
        
        guard let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) else {
            return completion(nil)
        }
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpg"
        
        imageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: metadata, completion: { [self] (metadata, error) in
            if let error = error {
                assertionFailure(error.localizedDescription) //   
 //Thread 1: Fatal error: User does not have permission to access gs://ios-post-193ec.appspot.com/images/2022-03-29T10:03:18Z.jpg.
                return completion(nil)
            }
            imageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    assertionFailure(error.localizedDescription)
                    return completion(nil)
                }
                completion(url)
            })
        })
    }
    
    func timeString() -> String {
        let now = Date()
        let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
        let datetime = formatter.string(from: now)
        print(datetime)
        return datetime
    }

}
```

as a result, I can't upload the image to storage

---

In this case, I have an error () as shown above. instead of the default image, one of the 6 permanent images that would be in the simulator had to come out.

[image: the appearance of the problem in the screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message shows that the user does not have permission to access the file. So it looks like you have [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security) controlling who can access the files in your Cloud Storage through Firebase, and those rules reject this read operation. I recommend checking the documentation I linked (there's also an old, but still great, video in there) to learn how to allow the operation, while still keeping the files secure.

Comment: mister, @Frank. Yes, the link you dropped are very useful. I have fixed a problem with the security section. Thank you for your attention.